# Redirect all users, except network administrators, from the main site to a subsite

Tags: multisite, redirect

I have a WP Multisite / Multi Network installation. What I need is to redirect **all non-logged** and also **all logged in** users, except logged in network administrators, from the main site *example.com* (including all nested pages, posts, categories etc.) to the *subsite.example.com*, that is a segregated multisite network. They share the same database. The network administrator will have access to the main site only after they will log in on the *subsite.example.com*. In this way, only the logged in network administrators must have access to the main site *example.com*.

**UPDATE**

The @seamus-leahy solution works, but only partially. I use his function in a multisite multi-networks installation and all networks in this configuration works like separated WP installations, so the network *example.com* will not recognize and log in automatically the network administrator when he/she is already logged in on the subsite.example.com (network 2), but logged out from the *example.com* (network 1). This means that the network administrator, in this context, also cannot access the main network example.com. How to solve this?

Comment: Can't you just run "!current_user_can('manage_network')" then redirect simply by adding a redirect in your head tag?

Comment: @christine-cooper, thank you! Will this work: _if( !current_user_can( 'manage_network' )) { header( "Location: http://subsite.example.com",TRUE,301 ); exit(); }_? And what solution will be the best/faster?

Comment: You did accept an answer that only partly works and added a new one to solve the missing part. Please don't do that. Work on the question, work on the answer, update your question with new and additional info occasionally.

Comment: Oh, and there's [`is_super_admin()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_super_admin/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to tie into `template_redirect` hook where you will check the site and the user and then redirect if needed.

```
function redirect_to_subsite() {
    if( is_main_site() && !current_user_can('manage_network') ) {
        $blog_id = 5; // <<----- Update the ID to the subsite blog ID you want to redirect to
         wp_redirect( get_site_url( $blog_id ) );
         exit();
     }
 }
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_subsite' );
```

Comment: @lurie A redirect head tag will be slower. This sends a short HTTP header to redirect instead of a a full HTTP header along with the page content. You are getting "Call to undefined function..." because your redirect code is before the `is_main_site()` function is included via `/wp-blog-header.php` file. If you place your code afterwards, you'll still get error as at that point the page has already been sent to the user.