# Login network administrators automatically in multisite networks

Tags: multisite, login

OK, I have [this function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165350) and it works, thanks to @seamus-leahy, but not exactly as I want, and not only because of this function. I use it in a multi networks installation and all networks in this configuration works like separated WP installations, so the network *example.com* will not recognize and log in automatically the network administrator when he/she is logged in on the *subsite.example.com*, but was previously logged out from the *example.com*. This means that the network administrator, in the context of multisite networks particularities and this absolutely necessary for my multi network function,  also cannot access the main network example.com. How to solve this?

Comment: @kaiser No, this is not duplicate! The mentioned answer not take into account the specific of multisite networks (see my improved question).

Comment: It is the exact same question. You just accept an incomplete answer that is missing the "network admin" part.